# Is it mandatory in the US to present the publisher's information on websites?

Tags: legal

In Germany it is (under certain circumstances) legally necessary to link to a page displaying the publisher's information of a website. This includes name, address, telephone number and email address.

Does such a legal necessity exist in the United States? If so, does it only apply for commercial websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No requirement at all. (land of the free and all that) However, if you are conducting business, then you need to establish trust. One way is to create a well formatted and marked up about page, a privacy policy page, and having the address and phone number in the footer or header of each page. It also helps with locale search and branding.